# Include clear command in cmd

Tags: cmd.exe

I know that `cls` is used to clear the screen in **cmd**, as `clear` command not available on **cmd**, being already used to **bash**, how can I add `clear` command in **cmd** to clear the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### How can I add clear command in `cmd` to clear the screen?

Option 1 - Use a batch file (`clear.cmd`):

```
@cls
```

Place `clear.cmd` somewhere in your `PATH`.

---

Option 2 - Use `doskey`:

```
doskey clear=cls
```

Notes:

- `doskey` macros cannot be used within a batch file (only from the command line), so go for Option 1 if you want to be able to use `clear` in a batch file.

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [doskey](http://ss64.com/nt/doskey.html) - Recall and edit commands at the DOS prompt, and create macros. You cannot run a Doskey macro from a batch file.

Comment: Even without entering the file extension `clear.cmd` definitely does the job.

Comment: @KleoBercero Of course. The extension is only required if you have `clear.exe` or `clear.bat` or whatever hanging out with `clear.cmd` :)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from setting alias by `doskey` which is stored only in the current session, meaning it will go out on `exit`, and creating and moving `clear.cmd` or `clear.bat` to `%SystemRoot%` or `%Windir%` to run them directly without typing their path, which are usually located at `C:\Windows\` path, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to clear the screen which is consistent (I hope) in both Linux and Windows.

The default extensions (to omit when writing the full name of the file) are stored in `PATHEXT` variable (check them by issuing `echo %pathext%`). This is an environment variable meaning it is permanently defined, and always there for you to refer. You can set it permanently by `setx` (as `setx %pathext%;.new` which will keep the previous extension and add the new appending to the already existing ones).

The default path for *executables* (runnable files) to refer to is stored at `PATH` variable (`echo %path%` or `path` command).